# How to wait for collection to be set in meteor package development?

Tags: meteor, collections, package

I am writing my first meteor package. I started writing an app and thought it would be nice, to make one of the main functionalities available for others as open source.

I know in meteor you can make a variable globally accessible by adding an export in the package.js, but how could I do something like the following, assuming my export variable is called "MyPackage"(pseudo code):

```
.on(AppDefinedMyPackage, function(){})
```

in the moment this part of the app's code is run(outside of the package, of course):

```
MyPackage = new Meteor.Collection('test');
```

Comment: you mean notice when the app developer decides to overwrite your global variable? I don't think you can other than through polling, and checking whether the content of the global is still want you'd expect. Also, this is not a meteor but a javascript question.

Comment: @Christian Fitz But maybe there is something which Meteor already implemented to make this easy to do. Because I am sure that I once had a package where I gave a Collection as input and then the template would use data of this Collection. But I can't remember the name of that :(